# invalid object name 0x80131904

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to write my first .NET project but I ran to a problem :

```
public List<AuthorListItemModel> Search(AuthorSearchModel sm, out int RecordCount)
    {
    
        var q = db.Authors.Select(x => new AuthorListItemModel
        {
            AuthorID = x.AuthorID,
            AuthorName = x.AuthorName,
            ArticleCount = x.AuthorArticles.Count()
        });
        RecordCount = q.Count();
        sm.RecordCount = RecordCount;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.AuthorName))
        {
            q = q.Where(x => x.AuthorName.StartsWith(sm.AuthorName));
        }
        return q.OrderByDescending(x => x.AuthorID).Skip(sm.PageIndex * sm.PageSize).Take(sm.PageSize).ToList();
    }
```

In this query I tried to call my article count from author (many to many relation)
but it keeps telling me author invalid object name authorArticles HResult=0x80131904
And when I remove :

```
        public DbSet<AuthorArticle> authorArticles { get; set; }
```

Everything magically works out (I need authorarticles for aggregation root so i can't delete it )

Comment: `x.AuthorArticles` vs `DbSet<AuthorArticle> authorArticles` ? a != A - still not sure, how all that's connected, though. It's just something that hit my eye.

Comment: @Fildor its not the name , I changed it to see if its going to work but it seems making authorarticle to a dbset make it invalid object